# finding a user defined item in a list using a for loop

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
def main():
    list=["chocolate", "jelly", "biscuits"]
    eat=input("What do you wanna eat?")
    for i in list:
        if list.index(eat)==eat:        
            break
        else:
            break

    print("We have that in tray:", list.index(eat))
main()
```

In VB.Net this would work quite easily inside a For loop and it would be the idiomatic way to do it. Why doesn't it here? Also, this is NOT a duplicate of another question on stackoverflow in which users provide alternative methods/pythonic suggestions of doing a similar thing.

For teaching purposes, I need to use the for loop, and correct the structure given above.

How I could add in the conditional logic that would print "That item is not in the list", if the user enters anything other than what is in the list. I am looking for the most simple fix of my original code.

I did try the following things, but with resultant logic errors. With a  solution.

Try #1:

```
def main():
    list=["chocolate", "jelly", "biscuits"]
    eat=input("What do you wanna eat?")
    for i in list:
        if list.index(eat)==eat:        
            break
        else:
            print("that is not in the list")

    print("We have that in tray:", list.index(eat))
main()
```

Error:

```
>>> 
What do you wanna eat?jelly
that is not in the list
that is not in the list
that is not in the list
We have that in tray: 1
>>>
```

Try 2

```
def main():
    list=["chocolate", "jelly", "biscuits"]
    eat=input("What do you wanna eat?")
    for i in list:
        if list.index(eat)==eat:        
            break
        else:
            break
    print("that is not in the list")

    print("We have that in tray:", list.index(eat))
main()
```

Error:

```
>>> 
What do you wanna eat?jelly
that is not in the list
We have that in tray: 1
>>>
```

Try #3:

```
def main():
    list=["chocolate", "jelly", "biscuits"]
    eat=input("What do you wanna eat?")
    for i in list:
        if list.index(eat)==eat:        
            break
        elif list.index(eat)!=eat:
            print("that is not in the list")

    print("We have that in tray:", list.index(eat))
main()
```

Error:

```
>>> 
What do you wanna eat?jelly
that is not in the list
that is not in the list
that is not in the list
We have that in tray: 1
>>>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *the most simple fix*? How do you measure simplicity?

Comment: What I mean is, I don't want people suggesting the use of dictionaries, lambda or that I need to get rid of the for loop!. I just want the code I've put on there fixed and commented on. So, a print line added to the for loop to say "that is not in the list". I want it fixed USING THE FOR LOOP - not without. That is key

Comment: ...or enumerates!

Comment: Got it, answer updated

Comment: [`list.index(x)`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item. You were trying to compare this **index** to the value you gave, eat.

Comment: If you want to access item in a certain index, which is what you were doing, the correct operator is list[i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
def main():
    list=["chocolate", "jelly", "biscuits"]
    eat=input("What do you wanna eat?")
    for element in list:
        index = list.index(element)
        if element == eat:
          print("We have that in tray:", index)
          break
          # If the element is found, then print the message and stop the loop

        elif index == len(list) - 1:
          # Index starts form 0, then if you have a list with n elements
          # and you reach the element with index n-1, you have reached
          # the last element.
          print("that is not in the list")
          # if the element is the last in the list, and it's not
          # equal to the user input, then the user input is not in the
          # list. Print the error message.

main()
```

And using `enumerate`

```
def main():
    list=["chocolate", "jelly", "biscuits"]
    eat=input("What do you wanna eat?")
    for index,element in enumerate(list):
        if element == eat:
          print("We have that in tray:", index)
          break
        elif index == len(list) - 1:
          print("that is not in the list")

main()
```

Comment: I wanted a fix without another pythonic feature (such as enumerates)...but as you've mentioned enumerates, could you please provide (will be helpful for others too) the easiest way of doing this using enumerates. (ignoring my original code, and going for your solution using enumerates). I'm still however, waiting to see if anyone can answer the question re. the use of the for loop in python and why it appears to defy common sense, or the sort of sense some other languages have anyway...!

Comment: Also, could you explain the term "enumerate" in this line: for index,element in enumerate(list):    AND   explain this line  elif index == len(list) - 1: (particularly the -1, and what it is doing). Adding comments to your solution would be okay. Thank you in advance

Comment: `enumerate` (referring to the previous version of the answer) takes the list and generates a list of tuples like this `(index, element)`. For instance, your list `["chocolate", "jelly", "biscuits"]` will become `[(0,"chocolate"), (1,"jelly"), (2,"biscuits")]`. Then, by looping on that *tuple list*, you will get the first element of the tuple in `index` and the second element in `element`, for each tuple in the `enumerate(list)`.

Comment: Also, `enumerate(list)`, doesn't really create a list of tuples, but a *iterator*, which is a particular iterable object in python. Here for furhter readings: http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html

Comment: Thank you Ilario. Would it be possible please to also post an answer with the most elegant solution to the same problem using enumerate. This will be helpful to any learner ...

Comment: Here it is. If you're still interested in the VB.net comparing, please post you're VB.net code too.

Comment: Would you say to use enumerate is the most "pythonic" or idiomatic solution in terms of python programming. Would anyone be able to explain why this is? It does seem counter-intuitive, having come at it from vb.net programming

Comment: Another important question: In your code solution above, why is not possible to simply say elif element != eat, instead of elif index == len(list) - 1:. Or for that matter why does it need to be defined at all, if I used an ELSE.

Comment: I assume you want to print just one message: *we have...* if the input is in the list, *we don't have...* otherwise. Using your elif condition will lead to print, for each element in the list one of those messages until it finds the element of reach the end of the list. `elif element != eat` wil lead you to have, in the worst case, `n-1` messages *not have* and `1` message *have* printed.
Try to change them and see what happens, it's the best way to learn.

Comment: Also, the `enumerate` solution is a bit more pythonic. There are lot of ways to solve this problem. The most pythonic is the Carl Shiles answer, imho.

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    list=["chocolate", "jelly", "biscuits"]
    eat=input("What do you wanna eat?")
if eat in list:
    print("We have that in tray:", list.index(eat))
else:
    print("That is not in the list")

main()
```

Comment: This, I was able to do quite simply, but if you read my question above, I am trying, for teaching purposes, to understand better the use of the for loop in python. In VB, the above would have worked. I want to add the "else" INSIDE THE FOR LOOP. Or is that not possible? Your solution, good though it is, simply takes out the for loop which is not what I want.